# Jersey Streamingoutput of large data set

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

```
final StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
  @Override
  public void write(final OutputStream out) {
  dao.getData(
    query,
    new SdmxObserver(writerFactory.getDataWriter(sdmxFormat, out, properties), request
        .getRemoteAddr(), request.getHeader("User-Agent"), query.toString(), sdmxFormat
        .toString(), query.getlist()));
  }
};
res = Response.ok(stream, MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.sdmx.genericdata+xml;version=2.1"))
            .cacheControl(cc).lastModified(lastModified).header("Vary", "Accept,Accept-Encoding").build();
return res;
```

The database call to retrieve the data is taking long as the data is huge and for that before downloading the data in the browser it is taking long time and user thought the server is not reachable. How could we send the chunk of data by using multiple database query in the same web service response, so that the download starts quickly and keep adding the response when next query fetch the data from database.

Comment: You can check out the Jersey docs on [Chunked Output](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output)

Answer (score 1):

Paginate the response content into pages up to X records. This will allow the API to retrieve a single page of results at a time, one by one.

```
http://localhost/api/v1/resource?page=1&size=20
http://localhost/api/v1/resource?page=2&size=20
http://localhost/api/v1/resource?page=3&size=20
...
```

You can take a look at [`PageRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) and [`Pageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) defined in Spring Data when defining your API.

Comment: I agree. Pagination should almost always be added to collections. Here is a [complete example](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-page-sort-example) using Jersey with Spring Data and pagination.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But the issue is that the endpoint URL we can not change(As it effect lots of users). The endpoint URL fetch all the values from service and write into a xml/csv. So how it is possible for adding pagination. Also the endpoint is to download all the data in the file in one go. But as the data is huge, the query is taking long to fetch all the values. That time user assume the server is not responding. After the query get executed we are writing the data by using streamingoutput.

Comment: @SubhajitPal refactor for the endpoint to be asynchronous. Make it return the XML generation ID instead of XML content. Process the generation in the background in a separate thread (e.g. Spring @Async). Expose a second API for downloading the XML by ID while it's ready.